# SQL Server Include columns in non clustered index

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table it has around 30 columns in it, I am running a select query, I am getting key lookup in the execution plan,I have around 2 million records in that table. Is it good practice to have that thirty columns in include clause?, or is there any way to solve issue? I know include columns store that data in leaf level node to satisfy the query. What is that 900 bytes? Does it mean that length of all include columns should not more that 900 character?

Comment: Ir means that  the size of a single row in the index cannot exceed 900 bytes (exactly as it says) not characters. Different data types use different amount of space. For example, a `varchar` uses 1 bytes per character; thus a `varchar(10)` is 10 bytes in size. An `nvarchar`, however, uses 2 bytes per character; thus an `nvarchar(10)` is 20 bytes. datetime datatypes use different space as well ([documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) as do `int` and `decimal`. Plus you have the overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an index with the leading key being the main predicate of the query and including all other columns will speed up the query and replace the key lookup with an index seek. BUT and big but you are then storing the data twice just in a different order so a 100MB table becomes a 200MB table. If this is the single most important query of your application then then you might be able to justify that.

Brent Ozar has a general rule of thumb of '5 in 5'. No more than 5 indexes with no more than 5 columns per table. I say general because obliviously there are situations when that doesn't apply.

If you need all 30 columns then a key lookup in the execution plan is going to be the best bet, have an index on the main predicate and let SQL Server use the hidden PK on the index to a key lookup for the other columns.

900 bytes if the maximum size of a single row on an index, so that will depend on what data types all columns in the table are

Comment: @RamBhaskar no worries, you need any more help?

Comment: I have nonclustered index, it has 4 four fields in the index key, When I am searching the records using first field it gives index seek, But when I am using remaining columns, it does index scan. Multiple column on non clustered index will not be useful?